# Get all Names from xml-conduit

Tags: xml, haskell, xml-conduit

I'm parsing a modified XML from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.1.0.9/docs/Text-XML-Stream-Parse.html

Here's what it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<population xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://example.com">
  <success>true</success>
  <row_count>2</row_count>
  <summary>
    <bananas>0</bananas>
  </summary>
  <people>
      <person>
          <firstname>Michael</firstname>
          <age>25</age>
      </person>
      <person>
          <firstname>Eliezer</firstname>
          <age>2</age>
      </person>
  </people>
</population>
```

How do I get a list of `firstname` and `age` for every person?

My goal is to use http-conduit to download this xml and then parse it, but I am looking for a solution on how to parse when there are no attributes (use tagNoAttrs?)

Here's what I've tried, and I've added my questions in the Haskell comments:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Data.Conduit (($$))
import Data.Text (Text, unpack)
import Text.XML.Stream.Parse
import Control.Applicative ((<*))

data Person = Person Int Text
        deriving Show

-- Do I need to change the lambda function \age to something else to get both name and age?
parsePerson = tagNoAttr "person" $ \age -> do
        name <- content  -- How do I get age from the content?  "unpack" is for attributes
        return $ Person age name

parsePeople = tagNoAttr "people" $ many parsePerson

-- This doesn't ignore the xmlns attributes
parsePopulation  = tagName "population" (optionalAttr "xmlns" <* ignoreAttrs) $ parsePeople

main = do
        people <- runResourceT $
             parseFile def "people2.xml" $$ parsePopulation
        print people
```

Comment: Edited to add what I've tried so far and comments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly: parsing combinators in xml-conduit haven't been updated in quite a while, and show their age. I recommend most people to use the DOM or cursor interface instead. That said, let's look at your example. There are two problems with your code:

- It doesn't properly handle XML namespaces. All of the element names are in the `http://example.com` namespace, and your code needs to reflect that.
- The parsing combinators demand that you account for *all* elements. They won't automatically skip over some elements for you.

So here's an implementation using the streaming API that gets the desired result:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)
import           Data.Conduit                 (Consumer, ($$))
import           Data.Text                    (Text)
import           Data.Text.Read               (decimal)
import           Data.XML.Types               (Event)
import           Text.XML.Stream.Parse

data Person = Person Int Text
        deriving Show

-- Do I need to change the lambda function \age to something else to get both name and age?
parsePerson :: MonadThrow m => Consumer Event m (Maybe Person)
parsePerson = tagNoAttr "{http://example.com}person" $ do
        name <- force "firstname tag missing" $ tagNoAttr "{http://example.com}firstname" content
        ageText <- force "age tag missing" $ tagNoAttr "{http://example.com}age" content
        case decimal ageText of
            Right (age, "") -> return $ Person age name
            _ -> force "invalid age value" $ return Nothing

parsePeople :: MonadThrow m => Consumer Event m [Person]
parsePeople = force "no people tag" $ do
    _ <- tagNoAttr "{http://example.com}success" content
    _ <- tagNoAttr "{http://example.com}row_count" content
    _ <- tagNoAttr "{http://example.com}summary" $
        tagNoAttr "{http://example.com}bananas" content
    tagNoAttr "{http://example.com}people" $ many parsePerson

-- This doesn't ignore the xmlns attributes
parsePopulation :: MonadThrow m => Consumer Event m [Person]
parsePopulation = force "population tag missing" $
    tagName "{http://example.com}population" ignoreAttrs $ \() -> parsePeople

main :: IO ()
main = do
        people <- runResourceT $
             parseFile def "people2.xml" $$ parsePopulation
        print people
```

Here's an example using the cursor API. Note that it has different error handling characteristics, but should produce the same result for well-formed input.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Text.XML
import Text.XML.Cursor
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Text.Read (decimal)
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    doc <- Text.XML.readFile def "people2.xml"
    let cursor = fromDocument doc
    print $ cursor $// element "{http://example.com}person" >=> parsePerson

data Person = Person Int Text
        deriving Show

parsePerson :: Cursor -> [Person]
parsePerson c = do
    let name = c $/ element "{http://example.com}firstname" &/ content
        ageText = c $/ element "{http://example.com}age" &/ content
    case decimal $ mconcat ageText of
        Right (age, "") -> [Person age $ mconcat name]
        _ -> []
```

Comment: Thank you for the two methods of doing this!  The cursor API looks much simpler.  If I'm using http-conduit to do a POST (it's how I'm getting the xml), do I need to continue using xml-conduit or can I use the cursor API?  I am using httpLbs (lazy byte string) in http-conduit

Comment: Well, you'll still be using xml-conduit, since the cursor API is part of it. The most efficient way you could do this would be to use `sinkDoc` together with the `http` function. Though you can go the simpler route and just use `httpLbs` if you'd prefer.

Comment: Does the cursor API still avoid keeping the whole XML structure in memory at once? Nevermind, seems like it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454267/how-to-use-the-xml-conduit-cursor-interface-for-information-extraction-from-a-la?rq=1