# How to use the xml-conduit Cursor Interface for information extraction from a large XML file (around 30G)

Tags: haskell, xml-parsing, xml-conduit

The following question is based upon the accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748303/get-all-names-from-xml-conduit). The author of the accepted answer said that the streaming helper API in `xml-conduit` was not updated for years (source: [accepted answer of SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367423/streaming-xml-conduit-parse-results)), and he recommends the `Cursor` interface.

Based on the solution of the first question, I wrote the following haskell code which uses the `Cursor` interface of `xml-conduit` package.

```
import Text.XML as XML (readFile, def)
import Text.XML.Cursor (Cursor, ($/), (&/), ($//), (>=>), 
    fromDocument, element, content)
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
import Filesystem.Path (FilePath)
import Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS (fromText)

data Page = Page
    { title :: Text
    } deriving (Show)

parse :: FilePath -> IO ()
parse path = do
    doc <- XML.readFile def path
    let cursor = fromDocument doc
    let pages = cursor $// element "page" >=> parseTitle
    writeFile "output.txt" ""
    mapM_ ((appendFile "output.txt") . (\x -> x ++ "\n") . show) pages

parseTitle :: Cursor -> [Page]
parseTitle c = do
    let titleText = c $/ element "title" &/ content
    [Page (mconcat titleText)]

main :: IO ()
main = parse (fromText "input.xml")
```

This code works on small XML files. However, when the code is run on a 30G XML file, the execution is killed by the OS.

How can I make this code work on a very large XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cursor` module requires that the entire contents be in memory, which seems to not be possible in this case. If you want to process files that large, you'll need to use the streaming interface.

Comment: In that case, do you still recommend the streaming helper API in `xml-conduit`? Or is there another XML streaming library you suggest to use for this task?

Comment: The streaming helper API is still recommended, the comment you link to just points out that there are probably better ways to design the library these days. The library was originally written before conduit even existed, and modern conduit provides a lot of nicities that we'd probably take advantage of today with a rewrite.